# FORM: Name as sender instead of e-mail.

Tags: php, html, forms, phpmailer

I have a very basic form that uses PhpMail to send it's content but is there some way to change the "sender name" of the form from an e-mail adress to a name.

Example:
Instead of "from: form.ello@whatever.org" it says "From: Ello Recruitment" or whatever.

Here's the code i'm currently using:

HTML:

```
<form name="10_percent" action="http://www.whatever.org/recruit.php" method="post" style="text-align:center;">
<label for="description"><p>Description</p></label>
<textarea name="description" id="description" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send" style="width:88px; height:24px;"/>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$to = "xxx@whatever.org";
$subject = "Recruitment";
$epost_field = $_POST['description'];

$headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers = 'From: Ello Recruitment' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: xxx@whatever.org' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


$body = "$description_field\n";


echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=http://www.whatever.org\">";
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
} else {
echo "not working";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marcel was nearly there - you need to change the `From` header:

```
$headers = 'From: Ello Recruitment <form.ello@whatever.org>' . "\r\n" .
```

You may have trouble setting the From address on some servers, for example gmail doesn't let you do this arbitrarily.

I would recommend you use a library to send email from PHP as it will do all this kind for formatting for you correctly.